# How can I parameterize tests in Playwright to run only specific tests for different environments?

Tags: parameters, environment-variables, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, playwright

We are using Playwright Automation framework using Typescript to do our Testing. We have 3 different environments. Right now, our project is having different code base for TST and UAT( Dev and TST have same codebase). We have 3 different pipelines for each env which run from the same Testing repo, the main branch, so they are running on the common code. Our project and pipeline is configured in Azure Devops. For our project, there are 2 main modules. Code for only 1 module is deployed into UAT and Prod. But now the second module is being deployed into Dev and TST and will be deployed to UAT in 3-4 months. We have used '.only' tag to run the test cases from module 1 which is running across the all envs from the common branch. Now we need to also run the test cases which we have created for module 2 in Dev and TST. If we use the '.only' tag then the test cases for Module 2 will fail on UAT pipeline since the code is not there. There are 2 possible solutions to this

1. Create separate feature branches for each env and run the appropriate pipeline with the feature branch. This will have an overhead as we will need to maintain and push code to each branches.
2. Have some parameters for Module 1 and Module 2 and then use those directly as environment variables and configure them as variable in the pipeline for Azure Devops.
   The second approach seems a better one but I don't know what parameters I can use here and how can I achieve this.

Could anyone please help here.

Answer (score 0):

You could [put tags](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-annotations#tag-tests) on the tests and specify which to run with the grep command flag, which you can set as pipeline variables.

```js
test('Test 1 @dev @test', async ({ page }) => {
  // ...
});

test('Test 2 @dev', async ({ page }) => {
  // ...
});
```

Then use `npx playwright test -g @dev` to run all tests flagged `@dev`